# EvernoteSDK ERROR: findNotes: Failed to find notes (personal). Exception of type 'Evernote.EDAM.Error.EDAMUserException' was thrown

Tags: c#, oauth, evernote

Trying to incorporate [OAuth](https://github.com/shaunmccarthy/AsyncOAuth.Evernote.Simple) and [Evernote-Cloud-SDK-Windows](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows) together.

Both parts are working perfect independently. The OAuth returns an OAuth Token without an problem. The Evernote-Cloud-SDK-Windows allows me to fetch/print out all the notes that are associated to a User.

The error is being caused because with the `Evernote-Cloud-SDK-Windows` uses a DeveloperToken and I am trying to pass in an `OAuth` token, (I understand these are not interchangeable but I am just trying to have an OAuth process and return all the Notes).

Is there anyway in C# to have OAuth and return all the `notes` and `tags` from a users account?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

Turns out that my initial request to Evernote for a API key was only given with Basic Access. Reviewing over the Evernote docs showed that, you need to have full access to read from Evernote's API.